# Stop Core Data calculation?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a long running calculation with `Core Data`:

```
let contextTemporary = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
contextTemporary.parent = context

contextTemporary.perform {
    //long running calculation
}
```

Is it a way to kill it, break it, stop it?

Comment: I think "abort();" is used for breaking the loop in completion block. May be you can check condition in Block in which case you want to stop that operation. And to return previous state of Context may be you can use "rollback"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing in that block. There's no way to say, stop running that `perform` block I started. However,

- You can make the code in that block check an external flag (like a boolean named `cancel` maybe) from time to time, and stop running if its value changes.
- If your block is doing something like a long fetch, consider using `NSAsynchronousFetchRequest`, which can be cancelled.

Comment: How dangerous is access flag from different threads? I.e. write only from one thread, but read from many different? I have't met with any issue yet, but Bernstein's conditions do not allow this.

Comment: If you're concerned about it you can always use GCD to ensure that you check that flag on the same thread where you change its value. Look at `Dispatch` for Swift or `dispatch_async` for Objective-C.